# Raspberry pi capture desktop without any connected monitor

Tags: boot, script

I want to capture raspberry pi desktop without connected monitor. IS it possible to run a program capture with script at boot up and record the desktop? Or the raspberry pi must be connected with monitor to recognize that there is a port (monitor) ?

Comment: Are you wanting to capture a static image of the desktop or a video? What is the purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to set the resolution in config.txt along these lines:

```
# Set to allow monitor to be added after boot
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
# Set resolution to PAL @ 12180x1024 60Hz
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=35
```

See:

- [HDMI Configuration](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/hdmi-config.md)
- [Video Options](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md)

You can then use VNC to set the desktop up if the program you want to record is not automatic.

As for capturing the screen:

1. I use [scrot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrot) for single screen shots though [this article](https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/articles/take-screenshots-raspberry-pi) also covers GNOME screen shot
2. As for recording changes, there are many programs [Record My Desktop is one](http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/about.php) and [Simple Screen Recorder](https://www.maartenbaert.be/simplescreenrecorder/) that I've seen on the Pi